# Why does this tiny program give "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program"?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-6.0

I have a very minimal .NET 6 program:

```cs
using System.Numerics;

var transform = new Transform2(default);

public readonly record struct Transform2(Vector2 Position, float Rotation)
{
    public Transform2(Vector2 position) : this()
    {
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get an exception:

```
 System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at Transform2..ctor(Vector2 position)
```

[Reproducible dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLaItW)

Why does this happen? Is it a bug in the C# compiler?

Comment: This compiles OK in Visual Studio 17.0.1 - could it be just a problem with dotnetfiddle?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it compiles OK for me to, but fails runtime, both with Rider and `dotnet run`...

Comment: Certainly looks like some kind of bug - worth reporting to Microsoft, I think.

Comment: How you're running it doesn't matter for an error like that, be it Rider, `dotnet run`, Visual Studio...  It's like saying that your car has a problem and maybe the garage is to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Sohaiub Jundi's answer, I used [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgNwgJwAQBdkRgZwGYD2yYqAvKjAKYDuqAKlrocQEwAUAJpXhAK4A26AJQBuALAAoSQAEAzKmSUAxkQ6ocmXkvT1G+ImHZ5+BCDoAKBHFHRQCMADSpjpnQCUC6M3ZhDJAb0lUYNQ5XWx9VjYXM1QABysbHyFUEAwACygcNj8JENRAvPyQy2tbezJ4xPKYcSLggF9JBqA) to dig some more (that site is awesome!), turns out the latest Roslyn build flags this as a compiler error:

`error CS8982: A constructor declared in a 'record struct' with parameter list must have a 'this' initializer that calls the primary constructor or an explicitly declared constructor.`

So apparently it is a bug in the currently latest .NET 6 version, and will be fixed in an upcoming release.

A workaround for now is to explicitly call the full constructor with all arguments:

```cs
using System.Numerics;

var transform = new Transform2(default);

public readonly record struct Transform2(Vector2 Position, float Rotation)
{
    public Transform2(Vector2 position) : this(position, default)
    {
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking into this with [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNXIwJwYzIA+AAgAwAElAjAHQBycAthAgJYbIDcAWABQIgG5QEtIlAB2yMDna0AvLVkQA7rQAqCOQqUAmABS4IYKHAA2MAJRDRwygGZaSKLiyzrAT3cQ2Hi0hMSkuvryigjspgBqgTA4RrQACljI3DDc3gA0tGDWWLC0AEpYMLA5snYiAN4itE30bnoG0bEmCaTJtAAOGVnVdrQg0gAW3MgmtcLNtA1z883pmdneqv2D67KO8wC+IvtAA), you will find `this = default(Transform2);` in the constructor which is weird and seem to be a bug as mentioned by `Matthew Watson` in the comments. Any way, I don't see any reason not to change the constructor to `public Transform2(Vector2 position) : this(position, default)` which does not seem to cause this problem.

Comment: `this = default(Transform2);` looks suspect but it's perfectly valid for a struct. It allows you to fully initialize all members in one shot, and then initialize a subset of members on top of that.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, I never seen it before. This is good to know.